# Unable to provide initial liquidity on PancakeSwap testnet

Tags: bsc, liquidity-provider, pancakeswap

I'm trying to test transactions on my contract but I'm unable to add liquidity to PancakeSwap, using their interface doesn't even load metamask, and calling the contract fails.
I set up the router and factory correctly.
I even tried deploying a copypaste of Safemoon to see if that would work and it was a problem with my contract, but that doesn't work either.

Is there anything I should know?

Comment: did you figure this out? I also did the same thing. I'm able to create the pair but adding liquidity doesn't work even a https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1#writeContract It seems like everyone is asking this question but I haven't seen a workable solution